# What is the difference between a predicate symbol and a function symbol in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

There are a lot of questions and answers on what the difference a predicate and a function in predicate logic is on this website, but there is no question/answer on what the difference between a **predicate symbol** and a **function symbol** is.

Comment: There's no difference in the symbols themselves. The difference is in what you have decided to use them for.

Comment: A predicate *is* a function that maps entities/terms to truth-values/claims rather than to other terms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Predicate logic distinguishes between *terms* (formal expressions denoting elements of the domain of discourse, e.g., addition of numbers in arithmetic) and *predicates* (formal expressions denoting relations amongst elements in domain of discourse, e.g., the less-than relation in arithmetic).

A predicate symbol is an operator that combines terms and produces a predicate. E.g., in arithmetic $=$, $<$ and $>$ are predicate symbols.

A function symbol is an operator that combines terms and produces a new term. E.g., in arithmetic $+$ and $\times$ are function symbols.

Answer (score 5):

Once we interpret the symbols:

A function applied to one or more objects gives you another *object*, while a predicate applied to one or more objects gives you a *claim*

For example, under the standard interpretation for the language of arithmetic:

$1+2$ gives you the object $3$ (and  $1+2$ is *not* a claim)

$1<2$ gives you the claim that $1$ is smaller than $2$ (and $1<2$ is *not* an object from the domain)